# "Ramirez & Gee" model: I'd like a better understanding about G, M, and N terms

Tags: brewing, sugar

My goal: I want to simulate beer (and perhaps other drinks in a future) fermentation processes in software.

In the Ramirez & Gee fermentation models, there are three terms for sugars:

- G for glucose. This is a monosaccharide.
- M for maltose. This is a disaccharide.
- N for maltotriose. This is a trisaccharide.

The consumption rates (using ordinary differential equations which are not analytically integrable) use terms to reflect the consumption priority they call "inhibitor terms", so the maltotriose gets the highest consumption rate (asymptotically, actually) when the other two sugars are already consumed (and even authors consider maltotriose non-fermentable or negligible).

I have two questions here:

- How does this model extends to more sugars? (e.g. sucrose) Are sugars with the same... size... (e.g. fructose and glucose are both monosaccharide) considered together under the term G instead of just glucose?
- Will I lose a lot of precision if I only consider mono and di saccharide instead? Or are there oligo/poly saccharide that are non-negligible on fermentation I should consider?

(additionally, perhaps as in comment and not part of an answer: Any book recommendation having quantitative details on different sugars for this R&G model would be useful to me)

Comment: Hm, looking at the sources this seems to based upon very scientific papers. Do you have them yourself? Because I would then suppose that all explanations are in them. And outside of them, I doubt that anybody who doesn't have a copy could add more information.

Comment: This is the main paper I reached: https://repositorio.ufsc.br/bitstream/handle/123456789/213351/TCC.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y, but has no further explanation. Others face similar issues. I'm an IT enginner, not a biochemistry one, so have quite basic chemistry knowledge.

Comment: Sucrose is glucose and fructose. Searching a bit on the web seems to indicate that it ferments the same in beer as maltose, which is two times glucose bonded.

Comment: I also just found this: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/j.2050-0416.1987.tb04470.x

Comment: Thank you :). By reading that paper, it seems that "glucose inhibiting maltose" assertion in R&G is not considered true in the paper you gave me. They imply this varies from strain to strain. I give up with this, for the particular purpose I had.